# improvement of a mod_rewrite rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Could you have a look at the code below and say if this is the correct way to do it please.

In order to redirect from:

```
http://blog.exampledomain.com/2013/10/testpage.html
```

to

```
https: //exampledomain.com/blog/testpage/
```

I have placed the below rewrite rules in 2 .htaccess files:

1. In the .htaccess file in root of `exampledomain.com` I have placed:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.exampledomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blog\.exampledomain\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://exampledomain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```
2. In the .htaccess file in the blog folder in `exampledomain.com/blog` I have placed:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)\.html https://exampledomain.com/blog/$3/ [R=301,L]
   ```

Questions:

1. Is this the correct way to do it?
2. Does this mean in this setup we have 2 redirects? (which is probably not good for SEO) Should these be combined? How?

Comment: Does your _subdomain_ `blog.` point to the same document root as your main domain?

Comment: yes, the subdomain used to be a blogspot which is not used anymore and is replaced with the blog in the subfolder. But in the current setup the subdomain blog. has the same root.

Answer (score 1):

These two redirects should be combined into one.

In the .htaccess file in the document root of your subdomain (which looks it might be the same as the document root of the main domain? Or in the main domains .htaccess file - if this is a parent directory on the filesystem), try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?blog\.exampledomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d\d/(.+)\.html$ https://exampledomain.com/blog/$1/ [R,L]
```

When you are sure this is working OK then change the temporary redirect (`R`) into a permanent one (`R=301`).

**UPDATE:** To also redirect from: `http://blog.exampledomain.com/` to `https://exampledomain.com/blog/` and `http://blog.exampledomain.com/whatever` to `https://exampledomain.com/blog/whatever`, add the following directives *after* the above:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?blog\.exampledomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://exampledomain.com/blog/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! In order to redirect the https version too should the code be modified? in other words to be able to go from https://blog.exampledomain.com/2013/10/testpage.html to https: //exampledomain.com/blog/testpage/ as well.

Comment: Providing you are serving the content from the same place then there is nothing to change with respect to the HTTPS version.

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to ensure that the below happen too:  http ://blog.exampledomain.com/ to https: //exampledomain.com/blog/ and http ://blog.exampledomain.com/whatever to https ://exampledomain.com/blog/whatever

Comment: basically everything else should map across.

Comment: Thanks! So from: `http://blog.exampledomain.com/` to `https://exampledomain.com/blog/` and `http://blog.exampledomain.com/whatever` to `https://exampledomain.com/blog/whatever`

Comment: You also mentioned that "This assumes that you don't have any other subdomains hosted in the same place that end in blog!" In which part of the code exactly this assumption is made and is it possible to get rid of it?

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle those additional redirects. I've also removed the "assumption" in the `RewriteCond` directive. It now only matches `blog.example.com` or `www.blog.example.com`.